# Text box cleared using Jquery, but the value shows back after page reloads first time

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've a jquery [**daterange picker**](http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/) on my web form (ASP.NET). I cleared the Daterange picker using the code as follows

```
$('#txt_dtfrom').daterangepicker("clearRange");
 $('#txt_dtfrom').val('');
```

But when I reloads the page (f5), at server side the textbox shows no values. But when the page loads back the daterange picker loads the old range. Its looks like the textbox not empty too.

When we check the value of the textbox it says the value is there. But if do the reload again (F5), this not happening. This time the textbox is cleared correctly. That means only second time of the reload the textbox cleared using JQUERY reflected. Looks like the textbox value cached (Is that true). I thought that because its empty in server side too when we debug using break points

**EDIT**
I missed one point. Also the textbox is inside a table Every controls are in an update panel. So is there is any connecting bug? I mean a cache stuff?

Comment: can you add your html and model, which can help to understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your problem correctly, you might want to look into clearing the ViewState for that control.

Its been a while since I have used WebForms but I believe its something like this:

```
ViewState[nameOfControl] = null;
```

You will want to have that in your `Page_Load` event, probably after doing a postback check. That way the value isn't stored in ViewState when the page reloads.

Another way to do this is to clear your control in JavaScript/jQuery on document ready, basically wrapping what you have already in the `$(document).ready` event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txt_dtfrom').daterangepicker("clearRange");
    $('#txt_dtfrom').val('');
});
```

Comment: The ViewState part of my answer will address the caching.  The Javascript  part of my answer will clear the values regardless of caching, you just have to attach it to the right event.

Comment: I did the same I believe. But its not clearing in the first time reload.

Comment: You did the same what?  Cleared the viewstate or cleared through javascript?  What events have you tried attaching to?

Comment: I cleared the textboxes on window unload event in javascript and also at the page load event in server side. Also I tried with a non server HTML textbox which also retains its value after the reload for firsttime which is emptied using JQUERY. Thats why I worried of thats because of any Updatepanel cache..

Comment: Does this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820218/ajax-net-updatepanel-doesnt-delete-old-content relate to you?  Are you structuring your tables like that?